# error respons from amazon. Error: "parameter &lt;?x ml version failed a validation check: Extraneous whitespace for input value:

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

Error:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ErrorResponse><Error><Type>Sender</Type><Code>InvalidRequest</Code><Message>parameter &lt;?xml version failed a validation check: Extraneous whitespace for input value: ""1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;
&lt;AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"&gt;
&lt;Header&gt;
&lt;DocumentVersion&gt;"1.01"&lt;/DocumentVersion&gt;
&lt;MerchantIdentifier&gt;Outdoor_outlet_seller&lt;/MerchantIdentifier&gt;
&lt;/Header&gt;
&lt;MessageType&gt;Product&lt;/MessageType&gt;
&lt;PurgeAndReplace&gt;true&lt;/PurgeAndReplace&gt;
&lt;Message&gt;
&lt;MessageID&gt;736&lt;/MessageID&gt;
&lt;OperationType&gt;Update&lt;/OperationType&gt;
&lt;Product&gt;
&lt;SKU&gt;&lt;![CDATA[120754]]&gt;&lt;/SKU&gt;
&lt;ProductTaxCode&gt;A_GEN_TAX&lt;/ProductTaxCode&gt;
&lt;LaunchDate&gt;&lt;![CDATA[2012-01-26T14:44:51-0800]]&gt;&lt;/LaunchDate&gt;
&lt;DescriptionData&gt;
&lt;Brand&gt;&lt;![CDATA[Liberty Mountain]]&gt;&lt;/Brand&gt;
&lt;Description&gt;This is a description&lt;/Description&gt;
&lt;ItemType&gt;Sports "</Message>
<Detail/>
</Error>
<RequestID>441a3e91-437e-49a4-a232-452984f883da</RequestID>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Now, I haven't used XML very much but it doesn't seem to complicated.  I have been working on this problem for a few days now and I just can't seem to figure it out.  I know there has got to be something wrong with my xml I jsut can't pinpoint where.

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>"1.01"</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>Outdoor_outlet_seller</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>
<MessageType>Product</MessageType>
<PurgeAndReplace>true</PurgeAndReplace>
<Message>
<MessageID>' . rand(1,1000) . '</MessageID>
<OperationType>Update</OperationType>
<Product>
<SKU><![CDATA['. $product->getSKU() .']]></SKU>
<ProductTaxCode>A_GEN_TAX</ProductTaxCode>
<LaunchDate><![CDATA[' . date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:sO') . ']]></LaunchDate>
<DescriptionData>
<Brand><![CDATA[' . $brand[$product->getBrandId()] . ']]></Brand>
<Description>This is a description</Description>
<ItemType>Sports & Outdoors</ItemType>
</DescriptionData>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>';
```

I don't know what is wrong with it, but amzaon doesn't like it and I don't know why.  Anyone have similar problems? The amazon Documentation doesn't have anything.  I am getting somewhat desperate with this.  Thanks for any help :)

Comment: I corrected the formatting, but I still have no idea what you want to do. Please add a paragraph with a description of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I normally use amazon to buy books. I never needed to send them XML to do so. No idea what you're doing, maybe you're using their site wrong ;)

Comment: oh man, Sorry about that.  I guess I completely forgot to say what I was trying to do here.  I am trying to send a "submitFeed" request to list an item to amazons servers using curl in php.  Whenever I send it I get the error response posted above.  I have no idea what to do about it.  phihag -  What things did you have to change in the xml? Also, you say you edited the xml? So the xml up there right now is your edited version?

Comment: I am also running into a validation error when getting a report via the C# api. I currently have an open case with Amazon, if they provide any details I'll share them here.

Comment: I'm running into the same issue with the C# API.  Worked fine a couple of months ago, and now it's returning `_GET_FLAT_FILE_OPEN_LISTINGS_DATA_ failed a validation check`.  Hoping that you might have an answer from Amazon by now...

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have a charactor that the Amazon feed does not like.

Such as &,#,etc.